# input pattern for latitude longitude validation

Tags: html, regex, validation

I am trying to get the HTML5 input pattern attribute to validate a latitude longitude string as follows:
[29.71620257395901,-95.42931508327673]

Cannot seem to get the expression quiet right...

```
<input type="text" name="latlon" pattern="/\[[+-]?([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+\,[+-]?([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+$/" />
```

Comment: Instead of `pattern="/..regex../"` you should use `pattern="..regex.."`. And note that `pattern` attribute regex triggers on submit action, not as user types.

Comment: Note: the `<input>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
\[[+-]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+,[+-]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+]
```

Note that with all the optional parts, it can also match `.42931508327673`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9R1jeP/1)

Comment: Thanks, adding one more slash before the last bracket did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Latitude should lie between **-90 to 90** and
Longitude should lie between **-180 to 180**

So, the following regex will help to validate with latitude and longitude valid ranges

```
\[(\+|\-|)(([0-8]\d?)(\.\d+)?|90(\.0+)?)\,(\+|\-|)((\d?\d|1[0-7]\d)(\.\d+)?|180(\.0+)?)\]
```

Test Cases

```
[89.438483,67.348389] -  Valid
[90.39393,178.000] -  Invalid
[0.347347,78.49494] - Valid
[-20.5858,90.889] - Valid
[-78,-179] - Valid
[-78.48348,180.00] - Valid
[-78.384844,180.44] - Invalid
```

Regex Demo - https://regexr.com/61rnl